# Настройка .htaccess для Zend Framework 3

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework-3

Пытаюсь настроить виртуальный хост для работы с Zend Framework 3.

Как известно "точка входа" в приложение находится в файле `index.php` в папке `public`.

При обычном изменении `DirectoryIndex` при обращении к домену браузер сразу открывает то, что нужно, но... Совершенно не подгруржаются ресурсы (css,js,etc). Что впрочем естественно, т.к. они тоже находятся в папке `public`.

**Вопрос:** Какие настройки должны быть в `.htaccess` для корректной работы?

P.S. Возможности изменить конфигурационные файлы Apache по ряду объективных причин нет. Потому и приходится задействовать `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, всё-таки разобрался сам.

На всякий случай, опубликую в качестве ответа корректные настройки `.htaccess` для Zend Framework 3. Вдруг кому-то пригодится:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !\.(js|gif|jpg|png|css|txt)$ public/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: если серьезно, то вы не правильно настроили, у Apache рабочая директория должна быть public